# boto3 the config profile (myprofile) could not be found when executed in logrotate

Tags: boto3, logrotate

I want to upload some logs from an instance to S3. Log rotate config is below. Logrotate invokes a wrapper shell that calls on a python (2.7) script to perform the upload using boto3. I tried various ways of setting AWS_CONFIG_FILE

1. as OS global variable /etc/profile.d/my_aws_config.sh
2. using python to set the global variable

```
/var/log/secure
{
    rotate 1
    hourly
    missingok
    compress
    sharedscripts
    copytruncate
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
    lastaction
        /bin/sh -xv /opt/upload_to_s3.sh 
    endscript
}
```

It is a wrapper script that in turn passes parameters to a python script
with code:

```
import sys
import os
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

os.environ["AWS_CONFIG_FILE"] = "/root/.aws/config"

archive_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')
s3_client = archive_session.client('s3')

def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True

folder_path=sys.argv[5]+"/"+sys.argv[4]+"/{}"
print folder_path
upload_file(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2], folder_path.format(sys.argv[3]))
```

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/techarch-scripts/python.py", line 29, in <module>
    archive_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 80, in __init__
    self._setup_loader()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 120, in _setup_loader
    self._loader = self._session.get_component('data_loader')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 685, in get_component
    return self._components.get_component(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 924, in get_component
    self._components[name] = factory()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 158, in <lambda>
    lambda:  create_loader(self.get_config_variable('data_path')))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 241, in get_config_variable
    logical_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 301, in get_config_variable
    return provider.provide()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 398, in provide
    value = provider.provide()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 459, in provide
    scoped_config = self._session.get_scoped_config()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 340, in get_scoped_config
    raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (dev) could not be found
```

printing python's variables, it does look like the variable is getting set:

```
{'MAILTO': 'root', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/0', 'SHLVL': '5', 'PWD': '/root', 'LOGNAME': 'root', 'USER': 'root', 'AWS_CONFIG_FILE': '/root/.aws/config', 'HOME': '/root', 'PATH': '/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': '871', '_': '/usr/bin/python'}
```

and my profile is definitely there:

```
[profile dev]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/ec2-s3-role-for-dev
credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata
```

Comment: If you use AWS CLI with `--profile dev` it also errors out?

Answer (score 0):

[Named profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) in aws use the following naming pattern for profile named `user1`

```
[user1]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
```

You need to put just `dev` in the square brackets,  not `profile dev`:

```
[dev]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/ec2-s3-role-for-dev
credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata
```